# Linking Qt libraries to be compliant with LGPL license

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

I want to create a closed source app using the LGPL variant of QT. Therefore I have to put all my "closed" code into a DLL file in order to stay compliant. But I am struggling how to do it.

I am using QT 5.15 and CMake under Windows.

My "open" part is this simple file main.cpp:

````
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return _main(argc, argv);
}
```
````

and main.h:

```cpp
#if defined BUILD_MYLIBRARY
    #define MYLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
    #define MYLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

MYLIB_EXPORT int _main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

the corresponding function within my library looks like:

```cpp
#include "main.h"
.....
int _main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     .....
     return app.exec();
}
```

Currently i am linking my library against the QT Libraries like this (library's CMakeLists.txt):

```
.....
add_compile_definitions(BUILD_MYLIBRARY)

add_library(mylib SHARED
    ${my_sources}
)

target_link_libraries(mylib 
    Qt::Core  
    otherlibs
)
.....
```

and this is what the executable's CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
.....
add_executable(myexe WIN32
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(myexe
    mylib
)
.....
```

The problem is, that with this configuration, a user can't link his own QT Libs with my project as it is demanded by LGPL.

What can I change in my structure to achieve this?

Comment: _Therefore I have to put all my "closed" code into a DLL file in order to stay compliant._ As far as I know this is not necessary.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the requirement. IMHO, it's basically: You must link **Qt** using its DLLs. You may not change the **Qt** code or have to publish this. If you deploy your `.exe` with Qt DLLs every user is free to replace these DLLs with an own copy as long as they are binary compatible. That's all. (I don't understand your intention to make your `main()` a DLL. Actually, an `.exe` and a `.dll` are not that different technically. Maybe, I got it wrong...)

Comment: FYI: [Does the LGPL have different requirements for statically vs dynamically linked modules with a covered work?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#LGPLStaticVsDynamic) (I bookmarked this link as the discussion about what LGPL allows vs. does not allow arises again and again. Though, I consider this as better as ignoring any legality considerations at all...) ;-)

Comment: I think i misunderstood the requirements as Qt's FAQ states that the user must be able to "re-link the application", whereas the LGPL says "recombine or relink". I think "recombine" clearly includes the simple replacement of the Qt-DLL's. Thanks a lot for getting me on the right way!